# Asus fx503vd , hdmi 2.0 on paper but hdmi 1.4 in reality

Tags: display, hdmi, asus

I have an asus fx503 bd notebook and recently (2 months ago) I bought an 1080p@144hz monitor, and I noticed something strange, the notebook can only show maximum 120hz. After contacting the asus support , they confirmed that my laptop has an hdmi 2.0 .
After this I brought another laptop (weaker but newer) and it was able to show 1080p@144hz ( so my monitor-cable combo are fine).
After some research I found out that intel hd 630(the igpu that comes with my i5 7033hq cpu) only can have hdmi 1.4 unless it has a chip called lspcon.(I disassembled my laptop and searched around the hdmi port(where I believed the lspcon chip could be) and I found an empty footprint for a chip surrounded by multiple pads for capacitors/resistors).
So who's wrong here me claiming that my laptop had hdmi 1.4 or the asus support saying that the laptop has hdmi 2.0, and there is a way I can make my monitor work at 1080p@144hz?

Comment: Are the drivers up to date? Try to boot Linux (for example Ubuntu) from USB and check if it works there.

Comment: @gronostaj I already have linux (kali linux) on my laptop and all the drivers are up to date

Comment: Have you tested on Windows then? The point is to test another OS to rule out faulty drivers.

Comment: @gronostaj yea I use windows everyday , kali is more for ctf and other stuff